# Determine the value of a constant such that f(x,y) satistifes the properties of a joint probability density function

Tags: probability

This is a problem from an applied statistics and probabilities class I'm taking. How do you solve this?  The answer is supposed to be $C=0.5$, but I'm not sure how to get there...

> Determine the value of c such that the function $f(x, y) = cx^{3}y$
> for $0 < x < 1$ and $0 < y < 4$ satisfies the properties of a joint
> probability density function.

My attempt to solve this looks like this:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{4}cx^{3}y\:dy\:dx=1$$
$$c\int_{0}^{1}x^{3}\left [\int_{0}^{4}y\:dy  \right ]\:dx=1$$
$$c\int_{0}^{1}x^{3}\left [\frac{x^2}{2}  \right ]\:dx=1$$
$$c\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^5}{2}\:dx=1$$
$$c\times \frac{x^{6}}{12}\Big|_0^1 =1$$
$$c\times \left [ \frac{1}{12} -0\right ]=1$$
$$\frac{c}{12}=1$$
$$c=12$$

Note:  I've only taken calc 1, so I'm not sure if I'm doing this right.  Multivariable calculus was not a pre-req for this course, but here we are. I'm trying to teach myself how to solve these problems as I go from examples, but I seem to have gone wrong somewhere....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to plug in the bounds of your first integral. You should have

$$ c \int_0^1 x^3 \int_0^4 y \; dy \; dx = c\int_0^1 x^3 \left[\frac{y^2}{2} \right]_0^4 = 8c\int_0^1 x^3 dx$$

If you continue the work from here, you will get c = 0.5.

Comment: Thank you. I've been going crazy trying to solve this. There was another example in the book where somehow the bounds for the integral of y become terms of x, and that lost me completely.  This I can follow at least.

Comment: @CBRF23 That's so odd, the bounds shouldn't transcend like that. I'm glad this helps!